# Deleting all relationship then save another - just new are saved

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got a model one to many : one star can have multiple pictures.

when i update my star, i can add or delete picture. When i save the star , i delete all pictures on database, and the save new ones. Like this :

```
$star->pictures()->delete();
$star->pictures()->saveMany($picturesAdded);
```

But i think there is no commit between these actions, because only new pictures are saved. All pictures which were already in database and then are deleted, will be not saved at all. 
I think Eloquent keep in memory what it deletes, inserts or updates, and then it commits all of that.

So i don't know how to proceed ... I just would to be sychronized with database.

Does the $star->push() manage to do what i want ? Does it delete relationship which does not exist anymore, or does it just insert/update new relationship ?

If the first question is true, then how to do it ?

I tried :

```
$star->pictures = Collection::make($picturesAdded);
$star->push();
```

But i've got an error :

```
Unknown column 'pictures' in 'field list'
```

Hope you can help

**EDIT**

Maybe an example would be appreciate :

I got a Star with pictures [1,2,3,4]. I edit the star and now I got [1,2,5,6].
If i do what I wrote ( collection delete and then saveMany ) , I got now in my database [5,6] while i would like [1,2,5,6]

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `sync()` method. `sync()` makes it so that the only items for that relationship are the ones you pass in. The syntax is `$model->relationship()->sync($ids)` where `$ids` is an array of ids.

So all you would need to do, assuming `$picturesAdded` is an array of ids, is

```
$star->pictures()->sync($picturesAdded);
```

Documentation can be found in [Eloquent Relationships#Inserting Related Models](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models)

Comment: @dramixx In `$model->relationship()->sync($ids)`, the `$ids` _array_ can also take the form `[ $id1 => [ 'pivot_col' => 'pivot_val_1' ], $id2 => [ 'pivot_col' => 'pivot_val_2' ] ... ]`, which will let you `sync` the _pivoted_ data

Comment: @kishanterry I had no idea. Cool. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Welcome. Its there in the documentation link that you provided, specifically the _Many To Many Relationships > Syncing For Convenience_ section

Comment: Indeed, sync method is for many to many relationship, but in my case that's a one to many relationship. I just add an example in my post for a better comprehension